# message board / scrapbook in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, asp.net-ajax

I am asp.net developer
I need to know about how does scrapbook works in orkut?
I need to make an application in which the user can reply to each other
Upto the limit of 1000 characters

Comment: Since this is just a WebForm and a SQL Database with a NVARCHAR(1000) Column: What specifically is your problem? Or more precisely (for us that don't use Orkut, which is the vast majority of the Internet): What specific feature does Orkut have that you want to replicate?

Comment: @Jakub I think it needs some punctuation - edited

Comment: About the Orkut scrapbook: http://www.google.com/support/orkut/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=11796 Sounds like a facebook wall with basic rich edit. Which features of it are you trying to replicate? Like Michael says, you probably just need a database table with the from and to user plus the entry text that you can add to and read back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a very broad question so my answer is going to have to be quite broad in scope,

First things first we're gonna need a database to contain the data, I don't know what else is going into your site so lets go with a basic 2 table model.  You'll probably want to add more fields depending on your requirements.

```
Tables  users         ScrapbookPost
Fields  UserID (pk)   SBPID    (pk)
        UserName      ToUser   (fk)
        Password      FromUser (fk)
                      PostText
                      CreateDate
```

With that basic structure we can have users leaving each other Scrapbook posts

This SQL code would retrieve all posts on a users wall where @userPage is the userID of the current users page.

```
Select 
    u.UserName, PostText, CreateDate
From 
    users u inner join
    scrapbookpost sb on u.UserID = sb.FromUser
where
    sb.ToUser = @userPage
order by
    CreateDate desc
```

Seeing a conversation between two users would mean querying like this

```
Select
    u.UserName, PostText, CreateDate
From
    users u inner join
    scrapbookpost sb on u.UserID = sb.FromUser
where
    (ToUser = @userID1
    and
    FromUser = @userID2)
    or
    (ToUser = @userID2
    and
    FromUser = @userID1)
order by
    CreateDate desc
```

That's the basic data structure and queries you need! 
Give the users a webform to write posts and validate on the server side to make sure the posts are less than 1000 characters and don't contain any nasties like [cross site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) or [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

For their scrapbook pages use either [Stored procedures](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/stored_procedures_basics_p1.aspx) or construct your query manually then bind your results to an [ASP Repeater](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/aspnet_repeater.asp) for output.

To beautify things a bit you could consider allowing them some HTML formatting with a control like [this](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx) or rich text editing with a control like [this](http://rte.codeplex.com/).